# PDO sqlsrv está no phpinfo mas não funciona

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, ubuntu

Estou tentando acessar um servidor SQL Server de um outro servidor Ubuntu 16.04 usando o PHP, fiz todo o processo de instalação do drive informado pelo site da própria Microsoft e no phpinfo é mostrado o drive instalado como mostra nas imagens, porém quando vou conectar ao banco é mostrado o erro:

> Error!: SQLSTATE[HYT00]: [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired

[image: phpinfo na seção do PDO]
[image: phpinfo na seção do sqlsrv]

> PHP Version 7.1.3-2+deb.sury.org~xenial+1

Segue o código da conexão:

```
try {
    $db_host = 'HOST';
    $db_username = 'USER';
    $db_password = 'PASS';

    //$dsn = "mysql:dbname=test;host={$db_host}";
    $dsn = "sqlsrv:database=test;server={$db_host}";

    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $db_username, $db_password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

Comment: Está usando o php7? poderia colocar o código da conexão?

Comment: Estou usando o PHP 7.1.3

Comment: Se não estou em erro, é `sqlsrv` ou `odbc`, usa isto aqui para ver os prefixos: `var_dump(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());`

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "sqlsrv" [1]=> string(5) "mysql" }

Comment: @BrunoAgenor na tua conexão está `mssql`, o correcto seria: `new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database={$db_host}", "{$db_username}", "{$db_password}");`. vale a pena verificar isto [aqui](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php) também. E se puderes remover a resposta abaixo, e colares aqui na pergunta facilitaria.

Comment: Realmente @Edilson, coloquei o sqlsrv e agora está sendo mostrada uma mensagem diferente.
> Error!: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: An invalid keyword 'dbname' was specified in the DSN string.

Comment: Não escreve `dbname`, escreve `Database` mesmo.

Comment: Pelo link consegue ver isso e ficou:  
    `$dsn = "sqlsrv:database=test;server={$db_host}"; ` 
  
Porém recebo uma nova mensagem de erro:  
`> Error!: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712`

Comment: Mostra o erro como se a extensão não estivesse instalada, porém no phpinfo mostra o contrário

Comment: faça download da drive solicitada e vê o que dá.

Comment: O problema é que eu já segui todos esses passos, no final o link leva para esse tutorial:  `https://download.microsoft.com/download/C/D/B/CDB0A3BB-600E-42ED-8D5E-E4630C905371/Linux_4.0_Install_Instructions.pdf`

Comment: Depois de muito pesquisar percebi que a pasta `/opt` no servidor tinha sumido, criei ela e instalei o drive novamente, agora está sendo mostrado outro erro: `Error!: SQLSTATE[HYT00]: [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired`

Comment: Eu costumo usar o o freetds para conectar com o sqlsrv, tenho um container que eu uso para rodar laravel com o sqlsrv, esse é o link do dockerfile que eu uso para criar a imagem https://hub.docker.com/r/toninho09/laravel/~/dockerfile/

Comment: Consegui conectar, muito obrigado a todos que me ajudaram.  
  
O último foi resolvido especificando a porta do SQL Server que não estava rodando na porta padrão:  
`$db_host = 'HOST,PORT';`

Comment: Certo, poste a resposta aqui para encerrar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muito obrigado a todos que me ajudaram aqui, após recriar a pasta `/opt` no servidor (que a propósito ainda não entendi como ele foi deletada), e instalar novamente o drive esse link me ajudou: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlnativeclient/2016/10/20/odbc-driver-13-0-for-linux-released/

Depois disso o problema era que o meu servidor SQL Server não estava usando a posta padrão, usei o neststat para verificar a porta certa.
E esse é o código final:

```
try {
    $db_host = 'HOST,PORT';
    $db_username = 'USER';
    $db_password = 'PASS';
    $db_database = 'DATABASE';

    $dsn = "sqlsrv:database={$db_database};server={$db_host}";

    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $db_username, $db_password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

if ($conn) {
    echo "Connected!";
} else {
    echo "Error";
}
```